# Cannot read property function of null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hello I'm trying to test a function from a function but tells me this error.

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNextServiceIconStyle' of null
> ```

Code

```js
function IssueNextServiceIcon ({ nextService, intl }) {
 
return (
        <div styles[getNextServiceIconStyle(nextService.approaching, nextService.overDue)])}>
             <NextServiceIcon className={styles['icon']} />
        </div>

 )
    function getNextServiceIconStyle (approaching, overDue) {
    if (overDue) {
        return 'next-service-overdue'
    }
    else if (approaching) {
        return 'next-service-approaching'
    }
    return ''
    }
}
```

Test

```js
test('should', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<IssueNextServiceIcon {...mockPropsForComponent} />)
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    const expectedResult = 'next-service-overdue'
    expect(instance.getNextServiceIconStyle(true, false)).toEqual(expectedResult)
})
```

Any suggestion for the test?

Comment: Unless you show the entire component, it is unclear what is on the instance and/or what is exported.

Comment: That lines with styles[] seems to have a brace at the end that ends something that hasn't begun, and a bracket before it too.

Comment: @DavinTryon now is more clear?

Comment: @rrd now is better?

Comment: There are some unbalanced brackets as @rrd said..

Comment: @AbhinavKinagi I think now is correct...

Comment: @Jonathan that's not a correct syntax. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Clarity do a good test, and go to the return of overDue, but I have an error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Your <div styles ... line has )} at the end which aren't needed. If you're using an IDE it should highlight them for you. Also what is 'Eif' in the in the getNextServiceIconStyle method?

Comment: @rrd the Eif is from the coverage page that I copy the code

Comment: @Jonathan you are trying to access getNextServiceIconStyle from styles object, so either you have not declared styles object or it is typo error. i think what you are trying to write is styles={getNextServiceIconStyle(..paramsHere)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few syntax errors and unclosed braces, but if I understood your intent correctly, you'd do smth like this:

```
function IssueNextServiceIcon({ nextService, intl }) {
  function getNextServiceIconStyle(approaching, overDue) {
    if (overDue) {
      return "next-service-overdue";
    } else if (approaching) {
      return "next-service-approaching";
    }
    return "";
  }

  const styleKey = getNextServiceIconStyle(
    nextService.approaching,
    nextService.overDue
  );

  return (
    // Or if you need to pass className: className={styles[styleKey]}
    <div styles={styles[styleKey]}>
      <NextServiceIcon className={styles["icon"]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Regarding the test, you cannot use `wrapper.instance()` because this is not a class component. What you could do is to render your component and check that it has proper styles applied:

```
test('it should have correct styling', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<IssueNextServiceIcon {...mockPropsForComponent} />)
    expect(component.find('NextServiceIcon').prop('style')).toHaveProperty('color', 'red') // test for the actual css you have
})
```

Comment: The second function is in the first function

Comment: Now is better, so any suggestion for the test?

Comment: Added to the answer.